# How to edit legends of a chart from cell range

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

I have a list of legends and plot data in separate file. When I plot the data it creates legends as series1, series2, and so on. Now I want to replace the legends from cell list in other file. I can do that one by one from select data. But is there any way to replace all at once.

Here is the data looks like: Top row contains labels of x axis.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbWB6.png)

[Chart from data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeWjs.png)

[Legend list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxJ4A.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the data associated with that chart

Comment: The structure of your data likely influences a solution here.

Comment: Your data screenshot does not correspond to the hart from data screenshot, and the labels are even something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to apply the names for each series to the header row of the source data **before** you plot. Excel will automatically use the first row of your data as the axis / series labels - well mostly. Take the following example:

```
Time    Series A    Series B    Series C
1       10          12          16
2       9           18          7
3       15          14          19
```

Excel will initially incorrectly choose the header row as the x-axis data (and convert it simply to a number count 1, 2, 3 and 4), and plot rows 2 to 4 as three series on one graph. If you right-click on the graph, click "Select data" and then "Switch row/column", Excel will then correctly plot and label the three "Series A/B/C" vs. the "Time" column. Now proceed to update/change the series names in the source sheet header row, and it will auto-update in the graph.

**TL;DR:**

1. Make sure your graph data has a header row with text (any fake name will do for the moment).
2. Make sure Excel detects the row/column orientation correctly in the Graph "Select Data" dialogue box. If not, hit the "switch row/column" button.
3. Select the series names from the legend list column, (ordered as they appear in the source data), copy (CTRL+C), select the first "fake" series name cell in the source data sheet, paste (CTRL+V), paste menu (CTRL), and Transpose (T).

Comment: So the legend names and data should be in same worksheet?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to keep the names "live", as in they might be updated in the legend list (kind of uncommon for graphed data), you can link to it. The easiest would be to turn your legend list horisontal, as to match the orientation of your series names, then in the first series name cell enter a formula (i.e. `=Legends!A5`) and copy across. If you rather what to keep the legend list as is, you can use an array formula (e.g. `=TRANSPOSE(Legends!A5:A100)`). This works a treat in Excel 365. In older versions, edit with multiple cells selected and commit with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: They don't need to be in the same sheet. The series formula looks like `=SERIES(Data!$B$1,Data!$A$2:$A$6,Data!$B$2:$B$6,1)`, with arguments for series name, X values, and Y values. Each of these can be on a different sheet, but none can be split across sheets. See [The Excel Chart SERIES Formula](https://peltiertech.com/chart-series-formula/) for excruciating detail.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. What I meant is if you have a large number of series to plot, practically the series names have to be in the header attached to the data in the same each, otherwise you would need to edit each series' properties or SERIES formula separately.

Comment: @JonPeltier BTW nice article though on an often overlooked Excel function.